# How to position an background-image using an offset but not the linear gradient

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a `<select>`-Field.
(This is an IE10-only page, so interoperability is only my second concern...)

using:

```
select
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: url(images/select-open.png), linear-gradient(#e3dfdb 50%, #d3cec8);
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: solid 1px #adadad;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

select::-ms-expand
{
  display: none;
}
```

I get something like:
[image: Imeg too far right]

Now, if I modify the backgroud position to `background-position: right 10px center;` then I get something like [image: white padding right].

How can I position the image 10px from the right border while keeping the linear gradient "all the way"?
BTW: I feel that adding 10px of transparency to the right side of my image is not an option ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is separate the position for both the backgrounds using a comma..

```
background-position: FIRST_IMAGE_POSITION, SECOND_IMAGE_POSITION;
```

So in your case, image is first and gradient is second so it should be..

```
select {
  background-position: right center, 0 0; 
  /* Use pixels instead of right and center for better control... 
     where 1st parameter is x and the other parameter is y
   */

  /* Rest stays the same */
}
```