# have gradient background cover button across padding

Tags: image, css, button

I'm trying to have a button that changes to a gradient background when active. The buttons have an image + text. The image is offset 5px from the left margin. The problem is that when the active state is invoked the 5px padding is excluded from the gradient.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Button Testing</title>
    <style>
        .controls {
            display: inline;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        .button {
                padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
                border: 2px solid #666666;
                color: #000000;
                text-decoration: none;
                /* background: #dcdcdc url(static/16x16/arrow-black.gif) no-repeat scroll 5px center; */
                background: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.75) url(static/16x16/arrow-black.gif) no-repeat scroll 5px center;
                -moz-border-radius: 6px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        }
        .button:hover, .button:focus {
                background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1.0) url(static/16x16/arrow-color.png) no-repeat scroll 5px center;
                border: 2px solid #3013ED;
        }
        .button:active {
                background: rgba(159, 245, 245, 1.0) no-repeat scroll 5px center;
                background-image: url('static/16x16/arrow-color.png'), -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
                border: 2px solid #3013ED;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="scale-button" class="controls button">Scale it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The button looks like this in normal state:

[image: normal]

When I hover it is fine and looks like this:

[image: hover]

But when it's active I end up with the padding excluded from the gradient background.

[image: active]

Is there some way to adjust the padding so that the gradient background doesn't exclude the leftmost pixels? If I have to adjust the image so that no padding is required I can do that, but I'm hoping there is a better way.

Here are the two images I for the arrows: [image: black], [image: color]. They're both 16x16 images.

Comment: add negative margin on the image

Comment: I tried a couple approaches to adding negative margin to the background image but they generated errors. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position an background-image using an offset but not the linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520050/how-to-position-an-background-image-using-an-offset-but-not-the-linear-gradient)

Answer (score 0):

If you alter your code in the following fashion it will remove that offset. Change:

```
.button:active {
            background: rgba(159, 245, 245, 1.0) no-repeat scroll 5px center;
            background-image: url('static/16x16/arrow-color.png'), -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
            border: 2px solid #3013ED;
    }
```

to this:

```
.button:active {
            background: rgba(159, 245, 245, 1.0) no-repeat scroll 0px center;
            background-image: url('static/16x16/arrow-color.png'), -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse farthest-corner, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
            border: 2px solid #3013ED;
    }
```

Where the only change I made was on the `background` declaration from `5px` to `0px`

Comment: That change causes the arrow to jump left when I make it active. I can do that, but if I want the arrow to stay in the same place then I need to adjust all padding and pad the left side of the image. Maybe I'm asking too much - I want the image to stay where it is by using padding but I want the background gradient to use different padding. If I could set the background gradient padding to -5px that would work but I don't know whether that is possible.

Comment: You could try putting all the gradient business in a div that is the same size as the button with the hover, active, and focus qualities handling the qualitative change while the button can hold the image and functionality. That would allow the div to have paddings for the gradient, and the button to have paddings for the image.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see the image jump because I did not have the file =p

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding my answer on stackoverflow. Mine is a duplicate. The key answer is that there can be multiple background-position specifications that correspond to the multiple background images. Not to duplicate the entire post, but:

```
background-position: FIRST_IMAGE_POSITION, SECOND_IMAGE_POSITION;
```

Here's exactly what I was looking for:
[How to position a background-image using an offset but not the linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520050/how-to-position-an-background-image-using-an-offset-but-not-the-linear-gradient?rq=1)